# Astro Project not loading SRC folder and style tags

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, astrojs

I have just initialized a new astro repository by running

```
npm create astro@latest
npm run dev
```

but there the default project template does not work on my computer. This is how the page looks below.

[image]

However, upon initializing the same repository on a separate computer, this doesnt seem to be an issue (see below), and the file structure of the application seems to be different.

[image]

I see no reason why this should be happening as this is the default template for astro. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Things I have tried: 
- Using a different browser
- Reinstalling node_modules/packagelock
- Starting a new astro project/downloading existing projects from github (all have the same issue)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, the styles weren't loading when running npm run dev. Then I realized it was because I was running it from the Git Bash terminal, so I switched to PowerShell 7, and it worked!

You can try to solve your problem by changing your terminal :)